# ArcGIS Versioning - Conflicts option greyed out / disabled

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I'm relatively new to the world of Versioning and using SDE databases, and have come across a problem that I can't solve.

Summed up - the Conflicts option/button is greyed out/disabled, and I know there are conflicts in the versions.

I'm sure I am probably missing out a step, so hoping someone can educate me on what I'm doing wrong please.

Background - Using ArcGIS v10.3 and data is held within ArcSDE Database. There are two primary versions - Default and FieldEditing.  We have just started testing Collector, so each time a sync occurs, another version is created.  I am trying to reconcile, review and send changes manually, feature by feature, and post to the FieldEditing version.

My steps are:

1. Add data from Default database (where I have full permissions) to ArcMap
2. Change the version to one of the Collector versions
3. View version changes (at this point I can see that there is a difference between the Collector versions and the FieldEditing version)
4. Reconcile (Target version: DATA.FieldEditing, Define conflicts: by object, conflicts to be resolved: in favor of the Target Version)
5. Last week I am sure that I was then able to click the 'Conflicts' button and go through the conflicts one by one, but this is now greyed out/disabled.

I've also got an issue whereby last week I had one version which had over 600 conflicts and out of the 26 versions, today there is only one which shows that there are changes.  I have just had an error to say "License Connection Lost - Lost connection with license server for ArcGIS for Desktop Standard".

Comment: I think I have a better understanding now - conflicts are where the two versions have BOTH been changed and I have to choose which to keep. However, if one version hasn't been changed, then the reconcile and post will push all edits to a target - its all or nothing.  So, if my understanding is correct - what is the best method for choosing manually which features have been changed and choosing which edit to keep?

Comment: Versioning is an "optimistic" algorithm.  If you have true conflicts, **you** are the only one who can decide which is correct (or if a hybrid is necessary).

Comment: Thank you for input Vince, so in layman's terms what is the best method for checking through and amending individual changes? For example, I've got thousands of 'grass' and 'vegetation' features.  If an inspector goes out with Collector, changes some attributes, and sync's that data, a new version is created.  How do I then go through and find the features that have changed in that version and make amendments / accept the changes?